# Sharing connection between scripts for node-red application

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, node-red, philips-hue

I've been using node-red to trigger communication to a philips hue gateway. I have succeeded in triggering it the way I want. The issue is that I need the action to take place more immediately than my current implementation. The only reason there is a delay is because it needs to establish a connection. I've tried looking online but it doesn't seem that there is a simple way to send this sort of connection descriptor across python scripts. I want to share the descriptor because I could have one script that connects to the gateway and runs an empty while loop. The second script could then just take the connection anytime I run it and do its actions. Apologies if this was answered before but I'm not well versed in python and a lot of the solutions were not making sense. For example, it doesn't seem that redis would be able to solve my issue.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use Python? None of the (multiple) Hue Node-RED Hue nodes use Python at all, they are all pure NodeJS

Comment: Well the Philips hue API was for python. With node-red I can run any script with an exec module

Comment: The exec node is for scripts that run and return, not scripts that run for ever.

Answer (score 0):

As per @hardillb's comment the easiest to control the Phillips Hue is to use one of the existing Node-Red Hue nodes:

- https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-node-hue
  https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-huemagic

If you have special requirements that require use of the Hue Python SDK ... It is possible to use the node-red-contrib-pythonshell node to run a python script that stays alive (using the node's "Continuous" option) and have Node-Red send messages to the script (using the Stdin option). There's some simple examples in the node's test directory: https://github.com/namgk/node-red-contrib-pythonshell/tree/master/test.